# When are R-value references necessary?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, rvalue-reference

I understand that, without R-value references, *perfect forwarding* in C++ would be impossible.

However, I would like to know: is there anything else that *necessitates* them?

---

For example, [this page](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_02.html) points out this example in which R-value references are apparently necessary:

> ```
>   X foo();
>   X x;
>   // perhaps use x in various ways
>   x = foo();
> ```
>
> The last line above:
>
> - Destructs the resource held by `x`,
> - Clones the resource from the temporary returned by `foo`,
> - Destructs the temporary and thereby releases its resource.

However, it seems to me that a simple change would have fixed the problem, if `swap` were implemented properly:

```
X foo();
X x;
// perhaps use x in various ways
{
    X y = foo();
    swap(x, y);
}
```

So it seems to me that r-value references not *necessary* for this optimization. (Is that correct?)

So, what are some problems that could *not* be solved with r-value references (except for perfect forwarding, about which I already know)?

Comment: Move semantics? And actually, perfect forwarding doesn't need rvalue references per se, it only needs different type deduction rules. They used rvalue references for those new rules it because it came handy.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: What exactly do you mean by "move semantics"? Is it something other than what I showed above? (Also, what I mean is that perfect forwarding was not possible *before*, but now it is, because of R-value references. What else satisfies this criterion?)

Comment: Swap can't replace `X x = std::move(y);`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Hmm... but what problem is your example trying to solve, exactly? (Also, what's `y` in your example?)

Comment: `y` is  some `X` lvalue. I'm trying to solve the same problem as yours, but for a class without a default constructor. Also consider: `struct foo { non_default_constructible x; foo(non_default_constructible x) : x(std::move(x)) {} };`. You can't swap there. Swap can't replace any kind of move-initialization.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Regarding the first example (I'll get to the second after I understand the first :P) -- if `x` is supposed to hold the contents of `y` after that statement, then what is `y` supposed to hold at that time?

Comment: Nothing? Doesn't really matter. What do you think a `unique_ptr` holds after being moved from? You moved from it, it doesn't have an usable value. Because you only move from things you're discarding anyway. That's what move semantics are about.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Wait, then I'm confused -- what's the point of your example?! Why not just use `y` in your code instead of `x`? Or why not `X &x = y`?

Comment: Hmm, dunno. But the impossibility of doing that makes initialization on constructors and initialization of arguments by moving impossible. You can't swap into arguments either. My point is *swap isn't initialization*. You can't swap everywhere. Move semantics are actually a generalization of this idea of `swap`ing.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I don't understand your second sentence, but regarding your third -- what do you mean? Can't you `swap(x, some_argument)`?

Comment: `void f(some_movable t);`. Call `f` by moving something into the argument, but use `swap`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Wouldn't copy elision take care of optimizing that anyway? What's the point of moving?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12934/discussion-between-r-martinho-fernandes-and-mehrdad)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> So, what are some problems that could not be solved with r-value references (except for perfect forwarding, about which I already know)?

Yes. In order for the `swap` trick to work (or at least, work optimally), the class must be designed to be in an empty state when constructed. Imagine a `vector` implementation that always reserved a few elements, rather than starting off totally empty. Swapping from such a default-constructed `vector` with an already existing `vector` would mean doing an extra allocation (in the default constructor of this `vector` implementation).

With an actual move, the default-constructed object can have allocated data, but the moved-from object can be left in an unallocated state.

Also, consider this code:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(...) {return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(...));}

std::unique_ptr<T> unique = make_unique();
```

This is *not possible* without language-level move semantics. Why? Because of the second statement. By the standard, this is copy initialization. That, as the name suggests, requires the type to be *copyable*. And the whole point of `unique_ptr` is that it is, well, unique. IE: not copyable.

If move semantics didn't exist, you couldn't return it. Oh yes, you can talk about copy elision and such, but remember: elision is an *optimization*. A conforming compiler must still detect that the copy constructor exists and is callable; the compiler simply has the option to not call it.

So no, you can't just emulate move semantics with `swap`. And quite frankly, even if you could, why would you ever *want* to?

You have to write `swap` implementations yourself. So if you've got a class with 6 members, your `swap` function has to swap each member in turn. Recursively through all base classes and such too.

C++11 (though not VC10 or VC2012) allows the compiler to write the move constructors *for you*.

Yes, there are circumstances where you can get away without it. But they look incredibly hacky, are hard to see why you're doing things that way, and most important of all, make things difficult for both the reader and the writer.

When people want to do something a lot for performance sake that makes their code tedious to read, difficult to write, and error-prone to maintain (add another member to the class without adding it to the `swap` function, for example), then you're looking at something that probably should become part of the language. Especially when it's something that the compiler can handle quite easily.

Comment: Awesome answer! Just a follow-up though: Any idea if this is comprehensive? (i.e. any other reasons you know of that you didn't happen to mention?)

Comment: +1, note that Bjarne Stroustrup implemented *move semantics* without *rvalue-ref* and I have used the `swap` trick for the same purpose, and *perfect forwarding* can theoretically be implemented through a lot of pain (exponential explosion on the number of arguments). But *rvalue-semantics* is an enabling feature as the cost (and/or dangers) of implementing it manually make it *impossible* in practice. I don't think `unique_ptr` can be implemented at all in C++03. But think of this as with lambdas: they don't let you do anything that could not be done before, it just improves usability.

Comment: +1, more info:  Consider implementing the generic `vector<T>::erase(iterator)` member:  It has to "move" elements in the array backwards by 1.  If you implement "move" with "swap", then you've greatly penalized `vector<int>::erase(iterator)`.  If you implement "move" with copy assignment, you've greatly penalized `vector<vector<int>>::erase(iterator)`.  To optimize both of these cases you need "move" to mean "swap-like" in one case and "copy-like" in the other.  Continued...

Comment: ... Continue down this path for a couple of years (while also trying to solve the auto_ptr problem and perfect forwarding) and you'll eventually reinvent something very similar to rvalue refs. :-)